# How to change avrdude parameter in Arduino status log when uploading a program? avrdude.conf

Tags: bootloader, avrdude

Recently I custom bootloader optiboot for Arduino Uno to my custom board called Ardunesia xst X1-02, with Cortex M3 processor. I set avrdude as bootloader upload `tool = "X1-02_bootloader.upload.tool=avrdude"` in board.txt. It work normal which my board pretends to be Arduino UNO. But I want to change this log status:

```
 Using Port                    : COM6
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :
```

I want the status log to contain my custom board instead displaying atmega328. I changed and edit file in avrdude.conf which it seems the root of this problem. I added an inheritance in Atmega328 for my custom board, but It didn't work (still displaying atmega328). I know avrdude.conf is made for avr MCU, but I wonder there is a way to add our custom/non-avr mcu to display this status log? Thank You.

**Edit**: To make it clear I want to customing *avrdude.config* `C:\Users\yourPC\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17\etc` which its contain board ID for AVR device and I want to insert y device ID here, I inserted it on Atmega328 part parent like this:

```
part parent "m328"
    id          = "m328p";
    desc        = "ATmega328P";
    signature       = 0x1e 0x95 0x0F;

    ocdrev              = 1;
;

part parent "m328"
    id          = "m328pb";
    desc        = "ATmega328PB";     //another m328 version
    signature       = 0x1e 0x95 0x16;

    ocdrev              = 1;
;

part parent "m328"
    id          = "XST";
    desc        = "XST_X1_02";         //my board XST X1-02
    signature       = 0x1e 0x95 0x0F;   

    ocdrev              = 1;
;
```

I set the signature so the bootloader recognize my board as Arduino UNO and its work well. But it keep reading as Atmega328P and not displaying XST X1-02. Should I create my own signature? any advice? Thank you

**Problem Solved!** I need to changes `compile patterns` in *platform.txt* from `-DAtmega328_{build.board}` to `-DXST_{build.board}` which *XST* is my MCU name. Thanks everyone!

Comment: why would you make an ARM MCU pretend to be an Uno?

Comment: Arduino Uno is running on [ArduinoCore-avr](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr) while Microchip's ARM MCUs are using [ArduinoCore-samd](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-samd), ST's STM32 or PIC's 32 bits MCUs all have there own different Arduino Core. Are you sure you know what you are doing? Why you are trying to use an 8-bit AVR core for 32-bit ARM chip?

Comment: @juraj Thanks for asking, because I want to make 'optiboot' bootloader work on my ARM MCU. Optiboot by default design for AVR device. Next I modified my MCU's buffer and boot sector address to make the optiboot main program work. Its work fine, but I just wondering how to change the status log above to contain my Device ID.

Comment: @hcheung Yess I know that, I just assigned to make a bootloader for the new MCU. I found it easier to port a bootloader program from Optiboot which designed for AVR and used AVRdude as upload tool than using Bossac for ARM devices like arduino Due. Its works since I just porting the size of buffer and bootloader section address for it. Now it just likes the last step to display my Device ID in arduino verbose output. Or can you tell me how to make an arduino bootloader for arm devices? Because I found it more complicated than a bootloader from Optiboot

Comment: Arduino M0 uses avrdude for upload

Comment: @juraj Interesting, but I dont find ATSAMD21G18 was mentioned in _avrdude.conf_ `C:\Users\yourPC\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17\etc`. This file contain all device ID that using avrdude for upload

Comment: I think it reports as ATmega2560

Comment: @juraj Just checked it, it's not. But since I don't have Arduino M0 so I can't  figure it out. Thanks for your response